# How to set up vpnc with certificate auth, no IPsec group/secret?

Tags: ubuntu, cisco-vpn-client

I work for a company that has a Cisco VPN server set up with apparently certificate authencitation (and username/password), but no IPsec group/secret. How do I configure vpnc in Ubuntu to not prompt me for a group/secret, and just use the PEM file along with my username and password?